# Select max value for each company in list, display longest value per company per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I've looked at some of the other questions similar to this, but nothing I've found can quite get me there.

I have a table with multiple columns, but 3 of the columns are Company, Date, and WaitTime.

I want to select the longest WaitTime for each company and for each day. I'd like to display the results for the entire date range, showing each company and the longest wait time for that particular day.

Main Table

```
 Company  |  Date |  WaitTime
 A          11/10     5.2
 A          11/10     5.1
 B          11/10     4.8
 B          11/10     4.7
 A          11/11     5.0
 A          11/11     5.1
 B          11/11     4.6
 B          11/11     4.5
 etc
```

Desired Results

```
 Date  |  Company  |  WaitTime
 11/10    A           5.2
 11/10    B           4.8
 11/11    A           5.1
 11/11    B           4.6
 etc
```

I can have many hundreds of interactions with each company, each day, so I am trying to find the longest wait time for each company for each day.

The most recent version I have tried is this;

```
 SELECT
 Top 1 with Ties 
 CAST(Timestamp as Date) As Date,
 Campaign as Company,
 (IVR_Time/60.0) as WaitTime

 FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[New_Five9_CallLog] a WITH (NOLOCK)

 Where a.Timestamp >= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE())-1,-1)
 AND a.Timestamp < DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE()),-1)
 AND a.Call_Type = 'Inbound'

 Order By ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By Campaign Order by Timestamp)
```

However this isn't quite showing me what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions. For your sample data, this would look like:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by company, mydate order by waittime desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

`date` is ambiguous (because there is a datatype that has the same name), so I renamed it to `mydate`. If that column actually has a time portion, then you need to remove it before ranking, like:

```
rank() over(partition by company, convert(date, mydate) order by waittime desc) rn
```

Note that `rank()` allows top ties, if any.

Comment: @DavidCady: this produces the result that youw want for your sample data, as you can see in this db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2de4d9596164e48e93e0ecd010b037ec

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you a ton. I was able to use this to do exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You want it by date, so use:

```
SELECT Top 1 with Ties . . . 
. . .
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By CONVERT(DATE, timestamp) Order by WaitTime DESC)
```

I'm not sure what your query has to do with your question.  It is much more complicated than the data you are showing.

Comment: That was the last answer to a similar question that I was trying to alter to for my needs.